Whether it holds that ${\mathcal B}(\Omega)\bigcap \Omega_0={\mathcal B}(\Omega_0)$ for Polish space $\Omega$?
Given a Probability space $(\Omega,{\mathcal B}(\Omega),P)$, where $\Omega$ is a Polish space  and equipped with the distance
$$
d:\Omega\times \Omega \rightarrow [0,\infty).
$$
${\mathcal B}(\Omega)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\Omega$. $\Omega_0 \subset \Omega$ with $P(\Omega_0)=1$. Knowing that, equipped with the same distance function $$
d_0:\Omega_0\times \Omega_0 \rightarrow [0,\infty) \quad d_0(x,y)=d(x,y)\quad x,y\in\Omega_0.
$$
$\Omega_0$ is also a separable metric space.
My question is, whether can we get ${\mathcal B}(\Omega)\bigcap \Omega_0={\mathcal B}(\Omega_0)$?
In fact, let
\begin{equation}
B(x,\delta)=\{y\in \Omega,d(y,x)<\delta\} \quad x\in\Omega,\delta>0,
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
B_0(x,\delta)=\{y\in \Omega_0,d_0(y,x)<\delta\} \quad x\in\Omega_0,\delta>0.
\end{equation}
We have ${\mathcal B}(\Omega)\bigcap \Omega_0=\sigma(\{B(x,\delta)\bigcap\Omega_0,x\in\Omega,\delta>0\})$, respectively ${\mathcal B}(\Omega_0)=\sigma(\{B_0(x,\delta),x\in\Omega_0,\delta>0\})$.
It can be easy seen $B_0(x,\delta)=B(x,\delta)\bigcap \Omega_0$ for $x\in\Omega_0$ so that ${\mathcal B}(\Omega)\bigcap \Omega_0\supset{\mathcal B}(\Omega_0)$, but could we get ${\mathcal B}(\Omega)\bigcap \Omega_0\subset{\mathcal B}(\Omega_0)$? Or point out the inadequacy in my statement.

For $x \in X$, the set $B(x,\delta) \cap \Omega_0$ is open in $\Omega_0$ so that it belongs to $B(\Omega_0)$

By definition, the open sets of $\Omega_0$ are of the form $V \cap \Omega_0$ where $V \subset \Omega$ is open in $\Omega$. If you don't want to use the topological definition, you can show that there exists a small enough ball $B_{\Omega_0} (x_0,\epsilon) \subset B_{\Omega}(x,\delta) \cap \Omega_0$ with $x_0 \in \Omega_0$

@EvangelopoulosFoivos If $x\in\Omega_0$, there is no doubt that $B(x.\delta)\cap\Omega_0$ is open in $\Omega_0$. But when $x\not\in\Omega_0$, how can we get that?

Thank, I‘'ll think about it again.

Let  $\mathcal G$ denote the class of open subsets of $\Omega$ and  $\mathcal G_0$  the class of open subsets of $\Omega_0$. Then $\mathcal G\cap\Omega_0=\mathcal G_0$. Consequently,
$$
\mathcal B(\Omega)\cap \Omega_0=\sigma(\mathcal G)\cap\Omega_0=\sigma(\mathcal G\cap\Omega_0)=\sigma(\mathcal G_0)=\mathcal B(\Omega_0).
$$
I have used here, for the second equality,  a general commutation fact about traces and generators:
If $E_0\subset E$ are non-empty sets, and $\mathcal A$ is a  collection of subsets of $E$, then
$$
\sigma(\mathcal A)\cap E_0=\sigma(\mathcal A\cap E_0).
$$
The containment $\supset$ follows directly from the definitions because $\sigma(\mathcal A)\supset\mathcal A$. For the reverse containment, use the "good sets" logic: define $\mathcal H:=\{B\subset E: B\cap E_0\in\sigma(\mathcal A\cap E_0)\}$. Check that $\mathcal H$ is a sigma-algebra of subsets of $E$. And clearly $\mathcal H$ contains $\mathcal A$. Therefore $\mathcal H$ contains $\sigma(\mathcal A)$. In other words, if $B\in\sigma(\mathcal A)$ then $B\cap E_0\in\sigma(\mathcal A\cap E_0)$; that is, $\sigma(\mathcal A)\cap E_0\subset\sigma(\mathcal A\cap E_0)$.
